# How to manage webpack umd module dependencies (or create peerDependencies)

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack, jsx, umd

I have created with webpack a UMD module, the content (without compression) start with :

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
  if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
  else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define("bootstrap-styled", [], factory);
  else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["bootstrap-styled"] = factory();
  else
    root["bootstrap-styled"] = factory();
})(this, function() {
```

This library depend on `react` and for a signel Component within this library : `react-dom` (through `react-onclickoutside` package).

When I build this library with webpack and try to use it in a project. I have an error complaining about two copies of React, the second one has been bundled.

So I need to know what I am expecting as a Umd module.

I don't want to have React built, I want React to be a peer dependencies.

Am I supposed to see `react` as a parameter of this umd module ?

From a React application, how can I load this module ?

How do I exclude React? I have tried most of the documentations examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using the `externals` property. When externals are specified, they will be added as arguments inside of the UMD wrapper.

You can reference [this new guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#add-externals) from our new docs page!!